# Use single file input to attach multiple files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/mV8E7/2/) for reference

#### Problem:

Cloning a file input element and appending it to the document in IE 9.

#### Details:

I am trying to use a single file input to attach multiple files to the document, but the file input will only be invoked on a per item basis.

If you look at the fiddler, you will see there are multiple items, these items should have the ability to attach an image to each item.

This will work in Chrome, but I can't get it to work in IE9.  If I do `$(this).clone().appendTo($('body'));`, it will create a new one and append it, but when I post it to the server it turns out to be null.

I am using MVC4 and am using the following method signature to get the files:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id, IEnumerable<QuestionAnwserModel> userAnwsers, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> userAttachments)
```

I have tried with with just having file inputs and it works fine, but I don't want to have multiple file inputs all over the form.

Answer (score 0):

As specified here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp the id of an element has to be "unique"

So a better approach would be to have a separate upload field for each of your "questions". It would solve a lot of problems from the start.

Another issue is that you are submitting multiple fields with the same name. Try using "userAttachments[]" and you should post an array.

Comment: The `userAttachments[]` is for PHP.  I'm using MVC which can handle multiple elements with the same name being submitted to the server.  The file inputs having id's is irrelevant as it isn't used for anything other than the main one, which I blank the id out because it won't be used.